# ¿Cómo puedo verificar si una llave existe en un array y al mismo tiempo obtener su valor asociado?

Tags: php, array

Estoy trabajando en una función a la que le paso un valor y me comprueba si el mismo existe en un determinado array.

Pero yo quisiera obtener al mismo tiempo el valor asociado a esta clave.

La función que tengo es:

```
function getColor($intValue){

    $arrColors=array(1=>'red',2=>'black');
    var_dump(key_exists($intValue,$arrColors));
}
```

**Pruebas:**

```
getColor(1);
getColor(8);
```

**Salida:**

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Esa parte funciona, pero ¿cómo puedo obtener el valor al que está asociada la llave, manipulando el array lo menos posible?

Quisiera una salida como esta más o menos:

```
red
default-color
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casi lo tenias, simplemente es cuestión de añadir un condicional, ejemplo con el operador ternario:

```
<?php

function getColor($intValue){
    $arrColors=array(1=>'red',2=>'black');
    return (array_key_exists($intValue, $arrColors)) ? $arrColors[$intValue] : 'valor por defecto';
}

echo getColor(1); // red 

echo getColor(3); // valor por defecto
```

Sin operador ternario:

```
<?php

function getColor($intValue){
    $arrColors=array(1=>'red',2=>'black');
    if (array_key_exists($intValue, $arrColors)) {
        return $arrColors[$intValue];
    }
    return 'valor por defecto';
}

echo getColor(1); // red 

echo getColor(3); // valor por defecto
```

Comment: ¡Claro!, era eso. Uno se ofusca a veces... Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes suponer que existe accediendo a él directamente asignándolo a una variable y comprobar posteriormente su valor:

**ATENCIÓN: OPCIÓN DESACONSEJADA**

```
function getColor($intValue)
{
    $arrColors = array(1 => 'red', 2 => 'black');
    $valor = @$arrColors[$intValue];
    isset($valor) ? var_dump($valor) : var_dump('default-value');

}
getColor(1);
getColor(8);
```

De este modo se manipula el array lo menos posible, ademas con el operador `@`evitamos el warning en caso de no existir.

**EDITO**

A raíz del comentario de Xerif voy a ampliar la respuesta. Es cierto  que, aunque el término guarrería no viene en los manuales de programación, el uso de este operador está desaconsejado. El haber dado esta respuesta era para que se ciñese al requisito de "manipular el array lo menos posible".

Entiendo que manipular el array lo menos posible, tiene unos límites y la primera opción lo manipula demasiado poco.

He dejado la respuesta original avisando de que su uso está desaconsejado y añado esta alternativa que no hace uso de este operador:

```
function getColor($intValue)
{

    $arrColors = array(1 => 'red', 2 => 'black');
    isset($arrColors[$intValue]) ? var_dump($arrColors[$intValue]) : var_dump('default-value');

}
getColor(1);
getColor(8);
```

En ambos casos el resultado es el siguiente:

> red
>
> default-value

**A tener en cuenta**

Si un índice existe y está definido con el valor `NULL`, la función `isset()` devolverá un false, mientras que `array_key_exist()` nos devolvería true.

Si tuvieramos esta estructura:

```
$arrColors=array(1=>'red',2=>null);
```

Haciendo esta llamada:

```
 getColor(2);
```

Haciendo uso de `isset()` obtendríamos 'default-value' mientras que haciendo uso de `array_key_exists()` obtendríamos `NULL`.

Comment: El uso de `@` para esconder un error me parece una guarreria y esta desaconsejado. Existen formas de resolver esto limpiamente.

Comment: Me alegro de que corrigieras tu respuesta, te dejo mis puntos sobre todo por el esfuerzo y plantear otra posible solución con `isset` en caso de que no se deseen valores nulos. Un saludo.